# Как отключить изменение шрифта от системы на Android программе

Tags: android, шрифты, typeface

Как можно запретить изменение шрифта в приложение от системы. Клиент поставил другой системный шрифт и это влиять на программу.В программе стоить сторонний шрифт, который загружен в Assets и на каждый TextView указан шрифт через класс TypeFace.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если шрифт установлен принудительно, используя рут права, то этого избежать невозможно. Если пользователь хочет, чтобы все приложения отображались его собственным шрифтом, то кто вы такой, чтобы запрещать это?

Comment: Вот вам достаточно извращенное рещение еще: Можете попробовать переопределить у `TextView` методы, которые отвечают на использование определенного `typeface`, и подставлять туда свой. Еще можете переопределить у обычного `View` метод `draw()`, и вручную рисовать на канве текст выбранным вами тайпфейсом. Но лично я бы послвл заказчика в общеизвестное углубление, т. к. это не в его (вашей) компетенции - заставлять пльзователя использовать определенный шрифт